# aws cli won't update on OS X

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, pip, command-line-interface

There is a new version of the aws cli, but when i do `pip install --upgrade awscli` i get this:

```
Installing collected packages: pyasn1, rsa, futures, jmespath, six, python-dateutil, docutils, botocore, s3transfer, colorama, awscli
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-i7HlOi-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be two ways to fix this

## Better way

It would be beneficial for you to install brew [you can follow this link](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/) and then install python through brew. Then the way to avoid this is to use a virtual environment for python [such as this](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) and then make a virtual environment to work on your AWS account. Also, since you've installed everything through brew, you should never run into permission issues on your account.

## Highly Unrecommended Way

You could run your command as super user with:

`sudo pip install --upgrade awscli`, this should give pip permission to uninstall the required file, but it's also possible that it won't work. Using the brew version of python is definitely preferable.

Hope that helps.